# How to edit all records to fill all blank rows in a specific column/field with a value in ms access database using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-update

I have one button in user interface which I click once will update/edit all records in column/field Action containing the value 'Not yet Acted' to be filled with value 'Acted' and all blank records/rows in column/field DateRecieved will be filled with todays date. The code below is working and no error but it update/edit only the first row/record and the following rows/records are not edit or updated. Please help me.

```
atskoneksyon()

    atsrec = New ADODB.Recordset
    With atsrec

        .Open("Select * from ATS where Action='" & "Not yet Acted" & "'", atscon, 2, 3)

        .Fields("DateReceived").Value = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
        .Fields("Action").Value = "Acted"
        MsgBox("Updated")
        .Update()
    End With
    atscon.Close()
```

Comment: You have to either loop thru all the records updating each one - or better still just write an update query that will do it one step. Execute the query without any recordset

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over each record you wish to update the records.

```
With atsrec

    .Open("Select * from ATS where Action='" & "Not yet Acted" & "'", atscon, 2, 3)
    While Not .EOF
        .Fields("DateReceived").Value = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
        .Fields("Action").Value = "Acted"
        .Update()
        .MoveNext()
    End While
End With
```

or you can run the following update query which will be faster as it doesn't need to retrieve the records.

```
UPDATE ATS SET DateReceived=Now, Action='Acted'" WHERE Action='Not yet Acted'
```

Comment: Thanks FloatingKiwi. Both of them are working. Thanks for the help. Very much appreciated for your effort to answer my help.